# Remove Extra Quotation from string to json format properly

Tags: python, json, dictionary

e.g: I have a string like

```
{"key": {"value": "this," is the "value" of guy""}}
```

I want this string to come up in a format so I can load it using json.loads function of python.

```
{"key": {"value": "this, is the value of guy"}}
```

Is there any built in python function which can do it or any regex for it, I tried many regexes but with time for different string its getting worse.

Comment: What is *generating* that string? It seems like fixing the quoting upstream would be better than trying to somehow process it afterwards when the information has been lost.

Comment: where do you have a string like that? because that is not valid python.

Comment: In a http response, I am getting an script which has description part where they have words in quotation marks and commas in between,

Comment: e.g key is description and value is actual description of that house, and that description contains some words may be name of the city in quotation mark.

Comment: save the value of description to a python variable, then print the repr of it. You need to take a look at the actual way the string is stored. edit that into the question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with a lookahead pattern to match pairs of quotes that are followed by either a colon or a right bracket, and strip quotes from what's enclosed in the outer quotes:

```
import re
s = '{"key": {"value": "this," is the "value" of guy""}}'
print(re.sub(r'"(.*?)"(?=\s*[:}\]])', lambda m: '"%s"' % m.group(1).replace('"', ''), s))
```

This outputs:

```
{"key": {"value": "this, is the value of guy"}}
```

Comment: this is not working for a case like this
```
{"bucketConfig":"{"livelab": {"applicationNames": ["node-traveler-search-ui", "node-traveler-property-ui", "checkout-page"], "jsUrl": "https:u002Fu002Fcsvcus.homeaway.comu002Frsrcsu002Flivelabsu002Fpriceconsistencyu002Fpriceconsistency.b884c3fcd158c9a6aa20.min.jsn }}"}
```